# Экспорт таблиц с данными с ошибкой ORA-39087: directory name is invalid

Tags: oracle, bat

Создал bat-файл со следующим содержанием:

```
set ORACLE_HOME=d:\oracle\112

%ORACLE_HOME%\bin\expdp schemas=ecp INCLUDE=TABLE: 'ECP_CR_USER_SIMULATE', 'ECP_SESSION_VARS', 'ECP_UPLOADED_FILES', 'ECP_USEr_CERTS', 'S_ERRORS', 'S_PARAMS', 'S_SUBSYSTEMS', 'TEST_USERS' directory='d:\quest\projects' dumpfile='exp_data.dmp' logfile='exp_data.log'

PAUSE
```

По запросу в командной строке ввожу логин и пароль. 
Затем выходит сообщение:

> ORA-39002 invalid operation
>
> ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file
>
> ORA-39087: directory name D:\QUEST\PROJECTS is invalid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-DA339AA4-C040-4D3B-A85F-DD3E470D452A.htm#SUTIL907) сказано, в аргументе `DIRECTORY` ожидается *directory object*, созданный на уровне схемы БД, а не путь файловой системы сервера БД.

> ```
> DIRECTORY=directory_object
> ```
>
> The directory_object is the name of a database directory object (not the file path of an actual directory).

Создайте [директорию в БД](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_5008.htm#SQLRF01207) и ссылайтесь на неё в *expdp* и *impdp*:

```
create directory dmpdir as 'd:\quest\projects';

expdp ... directory=dmpdir ...
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все получилось. Правда пришлось еще экранировать кавычки в названии таблиц

Comment: Пожайлуста!  Может ешё в имена лога и дампа штамп времени добавить -  `set ts=%date%_%time:~0,5%`

Comment: Ок, попробую добавить